# How to handle or reset MFA, if user forgets/loses device used for MFA?

Tags: firebase

How to handle user losing device or access to MFA auth codes/device for gaining access to the app? Is there a flow to reset SMS OR TOTP MFA in case user is not able to access account or admin has to handle it?

I assume that only viable workflow is for user to submit a ticket for support and admin handling the resetting flow of MFA or provide multiple MFA approaches.